# clearInterval doesn't clear on click (but works fine on hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I’ve made a slider, it autoplays fine, pauses on hover and starts again on blur. Great.

But when you click, it starts a new interval and goes x2 as fast and I cant get it to clear?

Here is my code:

```
// Reset autoPlay() if a user clicks a nav button
$('#sliderNav a').click(function(e) {
    setTimeout(autoPlay(), delay);
});

// Auto play the slider
var delay = 4000; // 4 seconds
function autoPlay() {
    myInterval = setInterval(function() { 
        currentOffset += itemWidths[clickCount] // Add the current slides width to total offset
        $sliderWrap.animate({right: currentOffset}, 500, function() {
            clickCount++;
            // If this is the last slide when clicking .next, slide to clone then snap back to beginning.
            if ( itemWidths.length == clickCount ) {
                clickCount = 0;
                currentOffset = totalWidth;
                $sliderWrap.css('right',currentOffset); // Where we started originally
            }
        });
    }, delay );
}    
autoPlay();

// Stop autoPlay() on hover
$('#slider, #sliderNav a').hover(function() { 
    clearInterval(myInterval);   
},
// start autoPlay() on blur
function() { 
    autoPlay();
});
```

Actual working demo so you can see it for reals: http://www.jonheslop.com/canoe/

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when someone clicks?

Comment: lol, its because ur .hover is overriding ur .click!, u need to immidiately disable .hover on click

Comment: @SpYk3HH I tried that but removing the .hover() function didn't change anything…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass reference of function instead of function returned value

```
use setTimeout(autoPlay, delay); instead of  setTimeout(autoPlay(), delay);
```

you should clearInterval inside autoPlay so that it clear older setInterval if called again and again.

```
 var myInterval ;
    function autoPlay() {
         clearInterval(myInterval); // clear older setInterval.
        myInterval = setInterval(function() { 
             ..............
```

Answer (score 0):

use a global variable to store the id of the setTimeout:

```
var timer = 0;

$('#sliderNav a').click(function(e) {
    timer  = setTimeout(autoPlay(), delay);
});
```

...

```
// Stop autoPlay() on hover
$('#slider, #sliderNav a').hover(function() { 
    clearInterval(timer);   
},
```

....

Comment: The variable doesn't have to be global, it just needs to be accessible to both your set and clear functions.

Comment: Using clearInterval() on id returned from setTimeout() can't work. Plus what @epascarello said.

Comment: @Iqc - why are you saying it can't work ? Did you try it? Try it and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You got a bug

```
setTimeout(autoPlay(), delay);  <-- you are calling the function right away.
```

You need to drop the ()

```
setTimeout(autoPlay, delay);
```

Comment: Thanks, totally should have spotted that one!